# why sendgrid showing me a error message when I am trying to send email?

Tags: php, sendgrid

I am using following code to send email using sendgrid:

```
<?php
require 'sendgrid-php/vendor/autoload.php';
$sendgrid = new SendGrid("my_key");
$email    = new SendGrid\Email();

$email->addTo("to@gmail.com")
      ->setFrom("from@youremail.com")
      ->setSubject("Sending with SendGrid is Fun")
      ->setHtml("and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP");

$sendgrid->send($email);
?>
```

When I run above code it's showing me an error message which is bellow:

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to
>   function SendGrid\Email::__construct(), 0 passed in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\freelancer\mysite\test-email.php on line 5 and
>   exactly 2 expected in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\freelancer\mysite\sendgrid-php\lib\helpers\mail\Mail.php:851
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\freelancer\mysite\test-email.php(5):
>   SendGrid\Email->__construct() #1 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\freelancer\mysite\sendgrid-php\lib\helpers\mail\Mail.php
>   on line 851

I don't understand what I missed here?

**Update One:**

```
require("sendgrid-php/sendgrid-php.php");
$from = new SendGrid\Email("Example User", "from@gmail.com");
$subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun";
$to = new SendGrid\Email("Example User", "to@gmail.com");
$content = new SendGrid\Content("text/plain", "and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP");
$mail = new SendGrid\Mail($from, $subject, $to, $content);
$apiKey = getenv('my-key');
$sg = new \SendGrid($apiKey);
$response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($mail);
echo $response->statusCode();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($response->headers());
echo '</pre>';
echo $response->body();
```

Now I am using above method but it's showing me

> {"errors":[{"message":"Permission denied, wrong
>   credentials","field":null,"help":null}]}

Comment: Try using `sendTos('to@gmail.com')` instead of `addTo()`?

Comment: not working.. :(

Comment: Same error as before?

Comment: Yes, It's showing same error like before and now I am using another way to send email but it's showing me Permission denied, wrong credentials. Do you know why?

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie I have updated my question. Please check that.

Comment: It sounds like you aren't authorized -- do you have a valid api token?

Comment: @Nevermore  I just created the new API key after logged.

Comment: Is your sendgrid account active? If not, you won't have permissions to send mail, no matter which api key or authentication method you're using.